# Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF MouseMove event seems to be blocking MouseDown event

Tags: c#, wpf

So I am working in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and am just trying to add a Polyline to a map based on MouseEvents using WPF. I am using Bing Maps as a credentials provider (shouldn't matter) and Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF for actually displaying and working with the map (nuget package available).

**Here is my MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MinimumReproducableMapControlBug.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <m:Map
        x:Name="map"    
        CredentialsProvider="your_bing_maps_api_credentials"
        MouseDown="map_MouseDown"
        MouseMove="map_MouseMove"
    />
</Grid>
```

**Here is My MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MinimumReproducableMapControlBug
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Color _strokeColor;
        private Color _fillColor;
        private PointCollection _poly;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _poly = new PointCollection();
            _strokeColor = Colors.LightGreen;
            _fillColor = Colors.LightGreen;
            _fillColor.A = (byte)(255 / 2);
        }

        private void map_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            _poly.Add(e.GetPosition(this));

            //convert _poly point collection into location collection
            //so that the polyline can use it to display on the map
            var polyLocations = new LocationCollection();
            foreach (var viewportPoint in _poly)
            {
                polyLocations.Add(map.ViewportPointToLocation(viewportPoint));
            }

            var polyLine = new MapPolyline() { Locations = polyLocations };
            polyLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(_strokeColor);
            polyLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
            polyLine.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(_fillColor);

            map.Children.Add(polyLine);
        }

        private void map_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            map.Children.Clear();
            var polyLocations = new LocationCollection();
            foreach (var viewportPoint in _poly)
            {
                polyLocations.Add(map.ViewportPointToLocation(viewportPoint));
            }
            if (polyLocations.Count == _poly.Count)
            {
                polyLocations.Add(map.ViewportPointToLocation(e.GetPosition(this)));
            } 
            else
            {
                polyLocations[polyLocations.Count - 1] = map.ViewportPointToLocation(e.GetPosition(this));
            }

            var polyLine = new MapPolyline() { Locations = polyLocations };
            polyLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(_strokeColor);
            polyLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
            polyLine.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(_fillColor);

            map.Children.Add(polyLine);
        }
    }
}
```

**The issue is sometimes my click event fires sometimes it doesn't.** Interestingly when I click on the map to the left or right (it is infinitely scrolling) it always catches the click events and draws the poly in the center map.

**This is me clicking in the center map constantly and only a few of the click events actually fired as intended (a click event definitely fired whenever a vertex is added to the polyline):**
[image]

**This is me clicking off center. Notice that it is recording all of my click events now and the movement event is working properly as well:**
[image]

**Why does it seem like my move event is blocking my mouse down event when I click on the center map?**

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want, but creating a `var polyLine = new MapPolyline() ` each mousemove event, shouldn't be done.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! This actually helped a ton and now it is working! @JeroenvanLangen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED by not being stupid and creating a new MapPolyline every move event! Edit: OG answer in the question comments

```cs
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MinimumReproducableMapControlBug
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Color _strokeColor;
        private Color _fillColor;
        private PointCollection _poly;
        private LocationCollection _polyLocations;
        private MapPolyline _polyLine;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _poly = new PointCollection();
            _polyLocations = new LocationCollection();
            _polyLine = new MapPolyline();
            _strokeColor = Colors.LightGreen;
            _fillColor = Colors.LightGreen;
            _fillColor.A = (byte)(255 / 2);

            _polyLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(_strokeColor);
            _polyLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
            _polyLine.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(_fillColor);
        }

        private void map_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            _poly.Add(e.GetPosition(this));

            //convert _poly point collection into location collection
            //so that the polyline can use it to display on the map
            _polyLocations.Clear();
            foreach (var viewportPoint in _poly)
            {
                _polyLocations.Add(map.ViewportPointToLocation(viewportPoint));
            }

            _polyLine.Locations = _polyLocations;
            if (!map.Children.Contains(_polyLine))
            {
                map.Children.Add(_polyLine);
            } 
        }

        private void map_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            map.Children.Clear();
            _polyLocations.Clear();
            foreach (var viewportPoint in _poly)
            {
                _polyLocations.Add(map.ViewportPointToLocation(viewportPoint));
            }
            if (_polyLocations.Count == _poly.Count)
            {
                _polyLocations.Add(map.ViewportPointToLocation(e.GetPosition(this)));
            } 
            else
            {
                _polyLocations[_polyLocations.Count - 1] = map.ViewportPointToLocation(e.GetPosition(this));
            }

            _polyLine.Locations = _polyLocations;
            if (!map.Children.Contains(_polyLine))
            {
                map.Children.Add(_polyLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```